# nodejs socket.io in ubuntu 18.04 error running server node app.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io

I am trying hosting my first node.js socket.io server in ubuntu instance. I getting the error on running "node app.js"

```
/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:345
      ...options
      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)`enter code here`
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused due to installing an old version of Node.JS on your OS.

You can try updating to the LTS version. To find out what version your running you can run the command

```
node -v
```

Good Luck!